# tshark command to follow tcp stream without tcp length

Tags: tshark

when we follow tcp stream using command:

```
tshark -q -r test.pcap -z follow,tcp,ascii,0
```

will get the following output with TCP length in the middle of the streamed output.

How to eliminate the `tcp.len`? do we have any tshark command to print only TCP stream output not the `tcp.len`

```
Follow: tcp,ascii
Filter: tcp.stream eq 0
Node 0: 10.10.30.50:57887
Node 1: 10.10.30.95:4902
**1448**              ---> this is tcp length
POST /pushnotification/v1.0/message HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Host: 10.10.30.95:4902
Connection: Close
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpraHVsamFzaW1zaW0=
Content-Length: 1277

{"push-message":{"serviceName":"Sync App","TTL":"600","recipients":[{"uri":"sip:919880018501@lab.t-mobile.com"}],"channel":"","pns-type":"RCSPage","pns-subtype":"Chat","nmsEventList":{"nmsEvent":[{"changedObject":{"parentFolder":"https:///oemclient/nms/v1/ums/tel%3a%2b1234567890/folders/97d38f52-bed0-4046-8784-bb110e3b0ea3","flags":{"flag":["\\RECENT"]},"resourceURL":"https://resourceurl","correlationId":"75114622-099d-4503-8166-e84bd1b620dc","message":{"id":"1","store":"RCSMessageStore/Chat","objectURL":"https://data1","direction":"In","message-time":"2016-05-19T08:46:49-08:00","status":"RECENT","sender":"sip:1234","recipients":[{"uri":"sip:2345"}],"imdn-message-id":"75114622-099d-4503-8166-e84bd1b620dc","content":[{"rcs-data":{"sip-call-id":"005056884776-4d72-eb161700-1e2-571fa736-a0e46","feature-tag":"urn:urn-7:3gpp-service.ims.icsi.oma.cpm.msg.group","p-asserted-service":"urn:urn-7:3gpp-service.ims.icsi.oma.cpm.msg.group","contribution-id":"e0a1029e-a48b-4ca6-b185-299dada439be","conversation-id":"2dbc584e-
**38**   ---> this is tcp length 
fc46-4a37-9a56-c2b93246d788"}}]}}}]}}}
    **17**
HTTP/1.0 200 OK

    **35**
Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.6.6

    **37**
Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 19:14:17 GMT

    **2**

    **9**
Thread-1
```

Comment: The TCP length should always come before the HTTP header (just before `...HTTP/1.1...`). The one that is printed in the middle of the request body is a bit surprising... Is that an error in copy/paste?

Comment: No it's not an error .. tcp length is present in the request body too.. is there a way to follow tcp stream without printing tcp length

Comment: Not that I know of. I was thinking of removing the TCP length with an awk scripts, but if it can be printed in the middle of the HTTP body, it's not gonna work. Are you able to reproduce this? Are there always TCP length printed in the middle of TCP payloads?